# Is there a limit to how many updates of an app you can submit?

Tags: iphone, ios

Based on how things are done for my company, we issue updates very very regularly.  Is there a limit or regulation as to how many times you can send a new update submission for your app?

I have looked and googled for anything relating to this issue but haven't found anything yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer. No, there is not. You can submit as many updates as you can produce. Naturally, you will have to wait for acceptance to submit the next version while one is in review though.